# The Trigger for IsSelected property of TreeViewItem is not working in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have implemented a tree view in my wpf application. It displays the data fine, but now I want a border to appear around the selected tree view item. So, I specified the tree view header container with textblock control inside a border control. The border is displayed properly, but it does not change color according to `IsSelected` property of the tree view item. Here is the xaml that I used:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="StyleTreeViewItemContainer">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
</Style>
<TreeView Grid.Row="3" x:Name="TreeViewServer"  Panel.ZIndex="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StyleTreeViewItemContainer}">
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}"   DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ServerTreeViewItemModel}">
                            <TreeViewItem  AllowDrop="{Binding AllowDrop}" Margin="{StaticResource MarginTreeViewItem}"    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  PreviewMouseDown="TreeViewItemServer_PreviewMouseDown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="{StaticResource MediumFontSize}" Drop="TreeViewItem_Drop" >
                                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"  BorderThickness="1">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"></TextBlock>
                                    </Border>
                                </TreeViewItem.Header>
                            </TreeViewItem>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
          </TreeView.Resources>
  </TreeView>
```

Comment: The implicit Style in TreeView.Resources is probably ignored because you explicitly set ItemContainerStyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to base the `ItemContainerStyle` on `StyleTreeViewItemContainer` instead of adding an implicit `Style` to `<TreeView.Resources>:`

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="3" x:Name="TreeViewServer"  Panel.ZIndex="0">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleTreeViewItemContainer}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}"   DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ServerTreeViewItemModel}">
            <TreeViewItem  AllowDrop="{Binding AllowDrop}" Margin="{StaticResource MarginTreeViewItem}"    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  PreviewMouseDown="TreeViewItemServer_PreviewMouseDown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="{StaticResource MediumFontSize}" Drop="TreeViewItem_Drop" >
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"  BorderThickness="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: It is working for the item that is selected.But border is not removed for the item that is deselected.I also added code for the Trigger when IsSelected is set to false.But it is not getting called.

Comment: @VK you need to create default setter for `BorderBrush` to make it disapear after deselect, like `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>`

Comment: @mm8 Initially I do not see border.When I select a node the border appears. But when I select some other node, border on previously selected node does not disappear.

Comment: @sTrenat Thanx your advice worked. But I had to define the default borderbrush value in tree view resources, as it did not work when I defined it under StyleTreeViewItemContainer style.